# How can I keep a material-ui modal open onSubmit if there are errors in the form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui modal with a registration form.  I am trying to set it up so if a required field is left empty the form input element turns red and/or a toast message pops up.  If I put noValidate in the form it doesn't close and the field turns red, but if everything is filled out and the passwords do not match or their are errors from the backend in, like the email is already being used or anthing, the form closes with no error.  I commented almost everythign out just to try go get it to console log an error, but it just closes.  If I leave noValidate in the form element, the field turns red then the modal closes.

How can I keep it open if there are errors?

Here is here is the modal that file that is opened from the login page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import DotLoader from 'react-spinners/DotLoader';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
//import { signUp } from '../../actions/AuthAction';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  FormControl,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  InputAdornment,
  InputLabel,
  OutlinedInput,
  Paper,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import Visibility from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import VisibilityOff from '@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const RegisterForm = () => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword((show) => !show);

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //const loading = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.loading);
  const userInfo = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
  };

  const [user, setUser] = useState(userInfo);
  const { first_name, last_name, email, password, confirmPassword } = user;

  const [firstNameError, setFirstNameError] = useState(false);
  const [lastNameError, setLastNameError] = useState(false);
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState(false);
  const [confirmPasswordError, setConfirmPasswordError] = useState(false);

  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleRegisterChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  const registerSubmit = async () => {
    setFirstNameError(false);
    setLastNameError(false);
    setEmailError(false);
    setPasswordError(false);
    setConfirmPasswordError(false);

    dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_REQUEST' });
    try {
      if (user.first_name === '') {
        setFirstNameError(true);
      }
      if (user.password !== user.confirmPassword) {
        toast.error('Passwords do not match.');
      }

      // const { data } = await axios.post('/api/users/register', {
      //   first_name,
      //   last_name,
      //   email,
      //   password,
      // });
      // setError('');
      // dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_SUCCESS', data: data });
    } catch (error) {
      // setLoading(false);
      // setSuccess('');
      // setError(error.response.data.message);
      // dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_FAIL' });
    }
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <Grid container>
        <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', background: '#faf3f3' }}>
          <Typography variant="h4" component="h4" align="center">
            Signup
          </Typography>
          <form
            noValidate
            onSubmit={registerSubmit}
            align="center"
            sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          >
            <TextField
              id="first_name"
              label="First Name"
              name="first_name"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              required
              sx={{
                marginTop: {
                  xs: 1,
                  md: 2,
                  lg: 3,
                },
                width: '90%',
                alignSelf: 'center',

                marginBottom: 1,
              }}
              onChange={handleRegisterChange}
              error={firstNameError}
            />

            <TextField
              id="last_name"
              label="Last Name"
              name="last_name"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              required
              sx={{
                marginTop: {
                  xs: 1,
                  md: 2,
                  lg: 3,
                },
                width: '90%',
                alignSelf: 'center',

                marginBottom: 1,
              }}
              onChange={handleRegisterChange}
              error={lastNameError}
            />

            <TextField
              type="email"
              id="email"
              label="Email"
              name="email"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              required
              sx={{
                marginTop: {
                  xs: 1,
                  md: 2,
                  lg: 3,
                },
                width: '90%',
                alignSelf: 'center',

                marginBottom: 1,
              }}
              onChange={handleRegisterChange}
              error={emailError}
            />

            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '90%' }} variant="outlined">
              <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
              <OutlinedInput
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                endAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                      onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                      onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                      edge="end"
                    >
                      {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
                label="Password"
                onChange={handleRegisterChange}
                error={passwordError}
              />
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '90%' }} variant="outlined">
              <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
              <OutlinedInput
                id="confirmPassword"
                name="confirmPassword"
                type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                endAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                      onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                      onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                      edge="end"
                    >
                      {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
                label="Password"
                onChange={handleRegisterChange}
                error={confirmPasswordError}
              />
            </FormControl>

            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="sixth"
              type="submit"
              align="center"
              sx={{
                width: '80%',
                color: 'white',
                fontWeight: '700',
                marginBottom: 2,
              }}
            >
              Log In
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default RegisterForm;
```

Here is the code from the login page to open the modal:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(true);
  ...
  ...

 <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <RegisterForm />
        </Box>
      </Modal>
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but maybe in your case it's better to use MUI Alert https://mui.com/material-ui/react-alert/ instead of Modal, cuz I see that you are trying to implement its features with Modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to validdate the form with noValidate prop in the form tag so it was closing, so I removed it and it will now stay open and display the errors.

```
<form onSubmit={registerSubmit} align="center" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
  ...
  ...
</form>
```